# Replica of "for" loop in mongoose aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some code as this

```
const quizzes = await Quiz.find({});
        const filtered = [];
        for (const quiz of quizzes){
            const response = await Response.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        userID: `${userID}`, 
                        quizID: `${quiz._id}`
                    }
                }
            ]);
            if (response.length === 0){
                filtered.push(quiz._id);
            }
        }
       console.log(filtered);
```

I want to write a aggregate method to replace my for loop, how can I achieve this?
I assume there is no requirement to post my schema's, all I need is help with how to traverse a whole collection items and perform some query on them with some other collection.

Comment: Did you try use $group and $lookup resources on aggregate? I have a scenario closely equals to yours. If you want, I can post de code below.

Comment: @rpereira15 no I haven't tried it yet, please do post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$lookup` to join response collection and match `quizID` and `userID` not equal to input `userID`
- `$match` if returned `response` from lookup is not empty
- `$group` by null and construct array of `quizID` in `filtered`

```
const response = await Quiz.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "response",
      let: { quizID: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            userID: { $ne: userID },
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$quizID", "$quizID"] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "response"
    }
  },
  { $match: { response: { $ne: [] } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      filtered: { $push: "$_id" }
    }
  }
]);

const filtered = response.length ? response[0].filtered : [];
console.log(filtered);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zlG_bA7U-Y4)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, it would be great if you have provided models as well, but anyway if you want to remove for loop here what I suggest:

```
quizz_ids = quizzes.map(q => q._id);
const responses = await Response.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    userID: `${userID}`, 
                    quizID: { $in: quizz_ids}
                }
            }
        ]);
```